# Visual Studio 2019 intellisense shows red squiggles under every single namespace that is not a .NET one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

Visual studio 2019 intellisense shows red squiggles under every single namespace that is not a .NET one. The project builds and runs fine. If I open the solution in VS 2017 it opens fine with no errors.

I have deleted the .vs folder. How can I solve this problem?

edit:
It seems the shared projects have been lost. If I right click to add a reference the other projects cannot be found. I tried removing a project from the solution and re-adding it but the "shared projects" list is still empty. I suspect this is related to problem where intellisense can't find them either.

If I open the solution up in VS2017 after this, everything works fine so it appears to be related to VS2019 only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi rolls, what's your current project type? If you try to add a new project into the same solution, check the 'Shared Projects' tab, the newly project display or not? It is better to share your detail VS 2019 Preview version, the project type and detail steps to reproduce this issue, I will try to test it in my side check if it is a issue of VS 2019 preview or not, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also have a look at this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311063/intellisense-no-longer-finds-classes-in-other-proj.html#reply-313266, try to remove <Private>true</Private> from the .csproj files, firstly backup your solution, then have a test with this method.

Comment: I am using 16.0.0 preview 4.4 all new projects added do not show up in the "shared projects" tab. I can't offer a repro as our project is gigantic. @SaraLiu-MSFT we don't have issues with nuget, only with our own projects. Our own projects do not have the <Private> tag on themn.

Comment: Actually I can create a repor. Make a new solution, then right click and do "add new project". Now attempt to add a reference to the new shared project, the shared projects is empty and reports "no items found". It seems it is impossible to create a new solution with any shared class dll projects in VS2019

Comment: Seems we are not the only ones with this issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187643/intellisense-in-shared-projects-seems-broken-in-la.html

Comment: Repro here, extremely easy to reproduce. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34499

Comment: Thanks for your detail information, I tried to follow your steps to test in VS enterprise 2019 Preview 16.0.0 Preview 4.4, add a new C# Class library (.NET Framework) and a new C# Shared Project into the same solution, right click the Reference under the WPF project, click 'Projects' tab, it display the new C# class library project, click 'Shared Projects' tab, it display the new shared project, since the Share Projects should list the shared project type, since you added the class library, it should under the Projects tab, not the Shared Projects tab, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution is documented here:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/40082

> I was able to track down the root cause for this issue, and also
>   provided a workaround to @rolandh offline.
>
> Tagging @jasonmalinowski, who is expert on VS project system layer on
>   our team, and @tmat who has been investigating how to properly report
>   VS-specific diagnostics in Roslyn. Let me expand on the findings:
>
> 1. Provided solution has a two projects which have a circular reference
>
>    - Project P1 has a ProjectReference to project P2 and project P2 has a metadata Reference to P2.dll. Latter gets converted to a project
>        reference via our metadata to project reference conversion logic.
> 2. Above configuration leads our VS project code to throw an
>      InvalidOperationException in CheckNotContainsTransitiveReference
>      over here when attempting to add project and metadata references.
> 3. Above exception seems to get handled somewhere down the call stack,
>      so there is no user visible impact. However, it causes the project
>      state for P1 to get corrupt - it ends up with no documents, no
>      references, etc. This leads to a ton of cascading intellisense
>      errors in all projects referencing P1.
> 4. Building the project/solution on command line succeeds as P1's
>      reference to P2.dll is unnecessary.
> 5. Unfortunately, the above InvalidOperationException does not
>      translate to any diagnostic in the error list, so user is given no
>      information about what went wrong under the covers and how to
>      resolve their issue. Ideally, the circular reference, or in fact any
>      such project system anomalies for which we throw exceptions in the
>      Workspace layer, should be translated to diagnostics in error list
>      by VS layer, so it helps the user towards fixing their
>      project/solution. @jasonmalinowski do we have any issue tracking
>      such work? I can file one otherwise.

Basically somehow we got a circular reference in our projects (not possible via the UI) which causes a bug in the intellisense engine.

Removing this circular reference resolved the issue.